# mysql stored procedure call unable to access parameter value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure named create_new_db(p VARCHAR(45)) on mysqldb. The syntax is as follows.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `create_new_db`( p VARCHAR(45))

BEGIN

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS p DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `p`.`events`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS p.events ( yada, yada, ...)
```

When I call the stored procedure using the

```
Call mysqldb.create_new_db('new_db_name');
```

The procedure executes, the database and tables get created but the parameter i am passing in is NOT being accessed. The database that is created is named p and not the name paramter that i pass in to the procedure

I have tried assigning the paramater to a global variable within the script

```
@P = p;
```

I can then see that the parameter name that i am passing into the procedure is getting into the stored procedure but how come it not working ??

I am likely missing something obvious here but ... some help would be appreciated.

Comment: So if the database gets created, isn't it using the parameter that you passed in or is it just naming the database p?

Comment: when i call the procedure, i am passing in the name i intend for the db to be called, Call mysqldb.create_new_db('new_db_name'); what happens is that the db just gets named p each time. I am assuming that p should reference the paramter that is being passed in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create dynamic sql like that. You must use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'some dynamic sql stmt'`

You pass a string to it, so build your sql up in your stored proc, like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE concat('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ', p, ' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1');
```

and similar for your other `CREATE` statements

Comment: Got this working using your direction. I built up the command string first, then assigned that to a statement using PREPARE and then executed the statement using EXECUTE, I don't know if thats the most correct way of doing it ... but its working !!!  ...  EXAMPLE `    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_db`( IN db_name VARCHAR(45)) BEGIN SET @str =CONCAT('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ',db_name,' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1;'); PREPARE stmt1 FROM @str; EXECUTE stmt1; END `      **Thanks very much** for your input!!!